# pipe Certificate Signing Request into opennsl x509 command

Tags: ssl

In the openssl docs it states (at http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#INPUT_OUTPUT_AND_GENERAL_PURPOS) that the '-in' option

> specifies the input filename to read a certificate from or standard input if this option is not specified.

I am trying to figure out how to sign a CSR (using a private CA) using `stdin` to send the CSR. The following line generates an error

```
openssl x509 -req -CA CA.pem -passin pass:abcdefg -set_serial 40 "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----###########-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----"
```

(where ###### represents the CSR data)

The error is:

```
unknown option -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----###########-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

It takes the input to be an option.

Doing

```
openssl x509 -req -CA CA.pem -passin pass:abcdefg -set_serial 40 -in request.pem
```

where request.pem contains the EXACT same data that is between the two `"`'s in the first line is SUCCESSFUL.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your question is not really on topic here as we deal more with algorithms, math, and theory. I'm migrating your question to serverfault with the hopes that you'll get better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm, you're not providing the CSR on stdin, you're specifying it as a parameter. To provide it from stdin you either need to redirect it from a file, or pipe it from another command. For example:

```
echo "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----###########-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----" | openssl x509 -req -CA CA.pem -passin pass:abcdefg -set_serial 40
```

Or, if the CSR is stored in csr.pem:

```
openssl x509 -req -CA CA.pem -passin pass:abcdefg -set_serial 40 < csr.pem
```